# Cannot set property 'name' of undefined from $scope.account.name

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm making a small example to submit a form with user name and email.

I want to set a default value to the input, like this:

```js
let app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
  let account = {};
  
  // TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined
  $scope.account.name = 'Hermione'; 

  // TypeError: Cannot set property 'email' of undefined
  $scope.account.email = 'hermione@gmail.com'; 
  
  $scope.form_submit = function ($event, account) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    
    console.log('name', account['name']);
    console.log('email', account['email']);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="account.name" />
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="email" ng-model="account.email" />
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="form_submit($event, account)">Submit</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Error message:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined

or

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'email' of undefined

My first question: how can I fix it?

I also tried: replacing `ng-model="account.name"` with `ng-model="name"`. Then, `$scope.name = 'Hermione'`. It works fine. Sorry but I don't want to use this way.

The second case: I want to set default value via using `ViewData`. I've tried:

```
@{
    // I've set a breakpoint to check value before, ViewData["Name"] is not null
    string name = ViewData["Name"]?.ToString() ?? string.empty;
}
```

Then:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="account.name" value="@name" />
```

That input is always blank.

So, my second question is: what's wrong?

p/s: I've refered question: [Cannot set property 'x' of undefined in AngularJs [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35398623/cannot-set-property-x-of-undefined-in-angularjs). But it doesn't seem like my question. I can't find the answer there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller code, define the new object `account` under $scope as follows:

```
  ....
  // change let account = {}; to the following:
  $scope.account = {};

  // now you could set $scope.acount.name
  $scope.account.name = 'Hermione'; 
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
  var account = {};
  
  // TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined
  account.name = 'Hermione'; 

  // TypeError: Cannot set property 'email' of undefined
  account.email = 'hermione@gmail.com'; 
  $scope.account=account;
  
  $scope.form_submit = function ($event, account) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    
    console.log('name', account['name']);
    console.log('email', account['email']);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="account.name" />
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="email" ng-model="account.email" />
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="form_submit($event, account)">Submit</a>
  </div>
</form>
```